# zsh is in /usr/bin, but also in /bin, what is the difference?

Tags: zsh

The /etc/shells says it has `zsh` installed in `/bin/zsh`, but also in `/usr/bin/zsh`.

```
brgr@envy17:~$ cat /etc/shells 
# /etc/shells: valid login shells
/bin/sh
/bin/dash
/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
/usr/bin/tmux
/usr/bin/screen
/bin/zsh        <--
/usr/bin/zsh    <--
```

Now, the [internet](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Zsh) suggests me to use the one from `/usr/bin/`.

My question is: why? What is the difference between these two and why is bash for example only intalled at one path (`/bin/bash`)?

Comment: Check them out with `readlink` to see if and where do they link to; e.g. `readlink -f /usr/bin/zsh` and other one similarly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One is probably a symlink (or hard link) to the other.....but they are the SAME file.

Comment: To check, use `ls -l`. If one is a link of the other, you'll see `linkedName -> /path/targetName`

Comment: @kmort That'll only check if its a symlink. For hardlink, in the `ls -l` output, you'll see a link count > 1, and if you `stat` them, the inode number will be the same.

Comment: @mdpc Suggest you add the info from kmort and my comments to your answer.

Comment: Actually, both of them are links to `/bin/zsh4`, what I think is the actual shell. Thanks to all for their answers!

Comment: @derobert For me the link count of both file is 1, but they share the inode number. How is that possible? (I checked that they are not symbolic links.)

Comment: @FranklinYu check to make sure there isn't a symlink further up the path (e.g., /bin to /usr/bin or vice versa). Other than that, which filesystem are you using?

Comment: @derobert Thank you very much! That’s indeed the case. `/bin` linked to `/usr/bin` like in Arch Linux and Fedora.

Answer (score 12):

The contents of `/etc/shells` are more or less static and have nothing to do with the the presence of specific shells installed on a system.

The fact that there are two entries in your `/etc/shells` means only that if a user has either `/bin/zsh` or `/usr/bin/zsh` specified as their shell in `/etc/passwd`, both of them would be considered 'valid' by daemons that consult `/etc/shells` (eg. most FTP daemons).

To see the first available zsh in your path ($PATH) you can use the which command like this:

```
which zsh
```

Or whereis, which displays more information (the binary, source, and manual page files for a command):

```
whereis zsh
```

Answer (score 6):

When `/bin/zsh` exists, the *redundant* existence of `/usr/bin/zsh` has mostly the purpose of *portability* in the sense that you don't need to edit each and any scripts' *shebang* line, which, when using `zsh`, will likely address `/usr/bin/zsh`.

`zsh` is not considered a *standard* software, but many and ever more people are using it, even hardcore system administrators. And that's why more distributions tend to place it in `/bin/zsh` as well.

To come to the point: it is not a `zsh` issue, but a *feature* that ought to guarantee to boot a Linux (or historically, Unix) system into a defined state.

`/bin` is defined to reside in the root file system, while `/usr/bin` is not.

For the latter (among others), options include to have it on another disk (partition) or even on another machine, and mounted via NFS or other networking means.

So when booting a system without network support, or in case the network goes down accidentally, or when a disk crashes or a file system is corrupted, or just booting into single user mode without mounting anything, the files in `/bin` are still accessible.

The same applies to `/lib` and `/usr/lib`: in fact, anything beyond `/usr` is considered to not be vital for the basic system (also X11 is usually found somewhere in the `/usr` branch. And that's also the reason why root's $HOME is not `/home/root`, since `/home` is also considered to not reside in the root file system.

And if the system disk crashed? Or the root file system is corrupted? Well, then chances are that you can't even load the kernel...

Much of the above is not too critical for today's systems. NFS mounted `/usr/*` file systems are unnecessary, since disk space is cheap and available in vast amounts.

Even OS images are installed to a separate `/boot` file system in many installations, so that loading the kernel doesn't guarantee to be able to mount the root file system, but for that we have `initrd` these days, which holds a working initial root file system for kernel startup (in which, in fact, `zsh` will be missing in most cases).

It's also common practice to have a big root file system that includes the `/usr` branch, which has some advantages when cloning installations.

So, the traditional considerations that led to the distinction of `/bin` and `/usr/bin` (and the like) are a bit out of date, but are still implemented in recent systems.

(this was more an aside, but these are the facts)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ls -li /bin/zsh /usr/bin/zsh
19401918 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 861568 Feb  4  2019 /bin/zsh
19401918 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 861568 Feb  4  2019 /usr/bin/zsh
```

Matching i-nodes means they are hard-linked.

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility reasons. Some scripts use /usr/bin others use /bin. Several distros wish to move everything to /usr/bin since there's not much point in having /sbin and /bin anymore. One of the exceptions is bash, since `#!/bin/bash` has been used in countless scripts over the last decades, so providing /bin/bash for compatibility, with a symlink, is a good solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

they may be the same (check file sizes with ls -l) or /bin/zsh may be an static linked version

in my debian jessie booth are the same but i could play with `update-alternatives` to make /bin/sh a link to /bin/zsh-static

in case my system is missing any zsh link dependency i would be able to login if my shell is /bin/zsh (if it is linked to /bin/zsh-static)

this practice is the norm on solaris systems, where /bin/ksh is a lightweight version of korn shell, where the heavy all-the-features version lives on /usr/bin/ksh

/usr/bin precedes /bin/ in the path so if you don't specify which one you want you get the better shell by default