# What path should I set for the bash shell with usermod?

Tags: bash, shell

I connect to a server via ssh.

Now i wanted to set the shell to bash, because at the moment the shell is sh.

`sudo /sbin/usermod -s /usr/bin/bash santi`

Should i use `/bin/bash` or `/usr/bin/bash` or does it not matter?

Comment: Does Bash exist as `/bin/bash`? or as `/usr/bin/bash`? or in both places? If in both places, is it the same Bash? Is `/bin` symlinked to `usr/bin` maybe?

Comment: When i ls -la i see bash in both, in /bin and in /usr/bin, i can set both path with usermod. how can i find out if this a symlinked and and what does that matter?

Comment: You didn't say which system you're running, but at least if it's a recent-ish Linux distribution, these might be relevant https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242157/why-are-bin-and-sbin-now-symlinks-in-ubuntu-20-04 https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge https://lwn.net/Articles/483921/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One of them is probably a link to the other...
>
> Traditionally, shells (like bash, csh and zsh) are located in /bin - because a shell is needed even in single user mode or other times when /usr may be unmounted (/usr is often on a separate partition and may even be mounted through the network - thus not readily available in singe user mode).
>
> On the other hand, additional shells (than the default one/ones) aren't strictly needed in single user mode (unless root happens to use one of them), so it's natural to put such shells it in /usr/bin instead of /bin.

[what's the difference between /bin/zsh and /usr/bin/zsh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414643/whats-the-difference-between-bin-zsh-and-usr-bin-zsh)

Both `/bin/bash` and `/usr/bin/bash` are valid paths for the Bash shell executable.

The difference between `/bin/bash` and `/usr/bin/bash` is historical and depends on the system conventions and configuration.

Traditionally, Bash was installed in the `/bin` path on Unix systems, some modern Linux distributions store it in the `/usr/bin` path.
Most system create symbolic link from /bin/bash to /usr/bin/bash, which means that both paths are equivalent.

`/usr/bin` is the default location for user-level executables on most modern Linux distributions. This path contains user-installed executables and is typically not mounted until later in the boot process.

`/usr/bin/bash` is the path to the bash executable if it is installed in this location.

The symbolic link ensures that legacy scripts and applications that reference `/bin/bash` will continue to work correctly even if the Bash executable is installed in `/usr/bin`

You can use `/bin/bash` or `/usr/bin/bash` in the `usermod` command to set the shell for the user `santi`

Both will work correctly.

[zsh is in /usr/bin, but also in /bin, what is the difference?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71236/zsh-is-in-usr-bin-but-also-in-bin-what-is-the-difference)

[Differences between /bin, /sbin, /usr/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/sbin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308045/differences-between-bin-sbin-usr-bin-usr-sbin-usr-local-bin-usr-local)

[Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)

[Difference between /bin/bash and /usr/bin/bash](https://www.reddit.com/r/bash/comments/q6afff/difference_between_binbash_and_usrbinbash/)

[What is the difference if I start bash with "/bin/bash" or "/usr/bin/env bash"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206350/what-is-the-difference-if-i-start-bash-with-bin-bash-or-usr-bin-env-bash)

Answer (score 8):

The permitted shells are listed in the file `/etc/shells`.

Run the `chsh` from the `santi` account, without sudo. It will prevent you from using a non-permitted shell.

The administrator can set a non-permitted shell, but that's a bad idea unless you're deliberately setting up a user account with restricted access. One reason is that ordinary users can't change it anymore. Another reason is that distributions keep `/etc/shells` updated, so an upgrade won't prevent users from logging in, but if you use administrator powers to give an account a non-permitted shell, then the burden is on you to be careful not to lock that account out.

Comment: Software like `ftpd` treats users differently depending on whether their login shell is in `/etc/shells`.

Answer (score 5):

For determine what is the path of the `bash` executable on your system, you can use the following command:

```bash
command -v bash
```

You can list available shells on your system too:

```bash
cat /etc/shells
```

If you want an interactive way to set the shell:

```bash
chsh <userame>
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 4):

If bash is available both in `/bin/bash` and `/usr/bin/bash` (typically because `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin` due to [the /usr merge](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/)) it does not matter. Both will work *on this system*

I would however prefer to use `/bin/bash` over `/usr/bin/bash`, as that's the traditional location where it was installed, and it would be more compatible if run in other systems (if instead of being a manual step this was included on a script that might be run on multiple machines, or if the location of bash was for writing it on a shebang)